# Django - How can I create an intuitive, Medium-like text editor?

Tags: django, text-editor

I want to create a rich text editor that doesn't require *bbcode* and behaves like the one in **Medium**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to create one?

As many editors are available as packages for direct use (that do not require *bbcode*). See [this link](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/wysiwyg/) for a comparison.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just discovered Froala! Amazing!